# Cakephp4 don't accept Content Type application/json; charset=utf-8

Tags: json, cakephp, cakephp-4.x

I upgrade my application from Cakephp3 to cakephp4 but unfortunately I am unable to update the android app accordingly due to logistic issues. The android app makes HTTP calls with Content-Type `application/json; charset=utf-8` and cakephp4 keeps throwing bad request. Is there a way to get cakephp4 to accept this header as a stop gap measure before I collect all the tablets and update them accordingly?

Below is the error log:

```
1) App\Test\TestCase\Controller\Api\EmployeesControllerTest::testJwtTokenPost
Possibly related to Cake\Http\Exception\BadRequestException: "Bad Request"
#0 /var/www/html/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php(73): Cake\Http\Middleware\BodyParserMiddleware->process(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest), Object(Cake\Http\Runner))
#1 /var/www/html/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Routing/Middleware/RoutingMiddleware.php(166): Cake\Http\Runner->handle(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest))
#2 /var/www/html/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php(73): Cake\Routing\Middleware\RoutingMiddleware->process(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest), Object(Cake\Http\Runner))
#3 /var/www/html/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Routing/Middleware/AssetMiddleware.php(68): Cake\Http\Runner->handle(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest))
#4 /var/www/html/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php(73): Cake\Routing\Middleware\AssetMiddleware->process(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest), Object(Cake\Http\Runner))
#5 /var/www/html/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Error/Middleware/ErrorHandlerMiddleware.php(121): Cake\Http\Runner->handle(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest))
#6 /var/www/html/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php(73): Cake\Error\Middleware\ErrorHandlerMiddleware->process(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest), Object(Cake\Http\Runner))
#7 /var/www/html/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php(58): Cake\Http\Runner->handle(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest))
#8 /var/www/html/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Server.php(90): Cake\Http\Runner->run(Object(Cake\Http\MiddlewareQueue), Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest), Object(App\Application))
#9 /var/www/html/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/TestSuite/MiddlewareDispatcher.php(190): Cake\Http\Server->run(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest))
#10 /var/www/html/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/TestSuite/IntegrationTestTrait.php(499): Cake\TestSuite\MiddlewareDispatcher->execute(Array)
#11 /var/www/html/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/TestSuite/IntegrationTestTrait.php(401): App\Test\TestCase\Controller\Api\EmployeesControllerTest->_sendRequest('/api/employees/...', 'POST', Array)
#12 /var/www/html/tests/TestCase/Controller/Api/EmployeesControllerTest.php(41): App\Test\TestCase\Controller\Api\EmployeesControllerTest->post('/api/employees/...', Array)
#13 /var/www/html/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestCase.php(1415): App\Test\TestCase\Controller\Api\EmployeesControllerTest->testJwtTokenPost()
#14 /var/www/html/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestCase.php(1035): PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase->runTest()
#15 /var/www/html/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestResult.php(691): PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase->runBare()
#16 /var/www/html/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestCase.php(763): PHPUnit\Framework\TestResult->run(Object(App\Test\TestCase\Controller\Api\EmployeesControllerTest))
#17 /var/www/html/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestSuite.php(597): PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase->run(Object(PHPUnit\Framework\TestResult))
#18 /var/www/html/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/TestRunner.php(627): PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite->run(Object(PHPUnit\Framework\TestResult))
#19 /var/www/html/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/Command.php(204): PHPUnit\TextUI\TestRunner->doRun(Object(PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite), Array, Array, true)
#20 /var/www/html/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/Command.php(163): PHPUnit\TextUI\Command->run(Array, true)
#21 /var/www/html/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit(61): PHPUnit\TextUI\Command::main()
#22 {main}
```

and below is the token method

```
  public function token()
  {
    $this->getRequest()->allowMethod('post');

    $employee = $this->Employees
        ->find()
        ->select(['Employees.id','Employees.project_id', 'Employees.name'])
        ->where(['Employees.pin_code' => $this->request->getData('pin_code')])
        ->firstOrFail()
        ->toArray();

      $sites = TableRegistry::getTableLocator()->get('Sites');
      $currentSite = array('id' => 0, 'name'=> 0);
      $currentTransactionId = 0;
      $transactions = TableRegistry::getTableLocator()->get('Transactions');
      $previousTransaction = $transactions->find()->where([
        'Transactions.employee_id' => $employee['id']
      ])->order([
        'Transactions.created' => 'DESC'
      ])->first();
      if(!empty($previousTransaction) && empty($previousTransaction->photo_out)) {
        $currentSite = $sites->get($previousTransaction->site_id);
        $currentTransactionId = $previousTransaction->id;
      }
      $this->set([
        'success' => true,
        'employee' => $employee,
        'current_site' => $currentSite,
        'sites' => $sites->find()->matching('Projects', function ($q) use ($employee) {
          return $q->where(['Projects.id' => $employee["project_id"]]);
        }),
        'transaction_id' => $currentTransactionId,
        'data' => [
          'token' => JWT::encode([
              'sub' => $employee['id'],
              'exp' =>  time() + 604800
          ],
          Security::getSalt())
        ],
      ]);
      // Specify which view vars JsonView should serialize.
      $this->viewBuilder()->setOption('serialize', ['success', 'employee', 'current_site', 'sites', 'transaction_id', 'data']);
  }
```

and yes the middleware is set up in src/Application.php

public function middleware(MiddlewareQueue $middlewareQueue): MiddlewareQueue
{
$middlewareQueue

```
    // Catch any exceptions in the lower layers,
    // and make an error page/response
    ->add(new ErrorHandlerMiddleware(Configure::read('Error')))

    // Handle plugin/theme assets like CakePHP normally does.
    ->add(new AssetMiddleware([
        'cacheTime' => Configure::read('Asset.cacheTime'),
    ]))

    // Add routing middleware.
    // If you have a large number of routes connected, turning on routes
    // caching in production could improve performance. For that when
    // creating the middleware instance specify the cache config name by
    // using it's second constructor argument:
    // `new RoutingMiddleware($this, '_cake_routes_')`
    ->add(new RoutingMiddleware($this))

    // Parse various types of encoded request bodies so that they are
    // available as array through $request->getData()
    // https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/controllers/middleware.html#body-parser-middleware
    ->add(new BodyParserMiddleware())

    // Cross Site Request Forgery (CSRF) Protection Middleware
    // https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/controllers/middleware.html#cross-site-request-forgery-csrf-middleware
    // ->add(new CsrfProtectionMiddleware([
    //     'httponly' => false,
    // ]))

    // Add the middleware to the middleware queue
    ->add(new AuthenticationMiddleware($this));

return $middlewareQueue;
```

}

and below is the test method

```
  public function testJwtTokenPost() {
    $this->configRequest([
      'headers' => [
        'Accept' => 'application/json',
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
      ]
    ]);
    // $this->enableCsrfToken();
    $this->post('/api/employees/token', [
      'pin_code' => '1001'
    ]);
    $this->assertResponseOk();
    $this->assertResponseContains('success');
    $this->assertResponseContains('employee');
    $this->assertResponseContains('current_site');
    $this->assertResponseContains('transaction_id');
    $this->assertResponseContains('sites');
    $this->assertResponseContains('data');
  }
```

Below is my postman json call

[image]

Comment: Please check your error logs for the related error, and include it in your question alongside with the related stacktrace! PHP (not CakePHP) only processes form data, all other type of data must be processed manually, if you haven't setup CakePHP correctly to do that ([**Input parsing has been moved**](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/appendices/4-0-migration-guide.html#id1) from the request handler component to the body parser middleware), then you might run into errors.

Comment: @ndm updated with the error logs

Comment: What's the code of the `EmployeesControllerTest::testJwtTokenPost()` method, and with what configuration (if any) do you setup the body parser middleware in `src/Application.php`?

Comment: updated the question @ndm. how do I update src/Applications.php to include Content-Type?

Answer (score 0):

When testing non-`application/x-www-form-urlencoded` requests you must pass the data as a string, as the test case can't reliably make assumptions about how to possibly transform the data into a string itself.

ie, pass a JSON string as POST data, not an array, a string is how `application/json` data would be exposed by PHP for an actual HTTP request:

```php
$this->post('/api/employees/token', json_encode([
    'pin_code' => '1001'
]));
```

There's no need to further configure the [**body parser middleware**](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/controllers/middleware.html#body-parser-middleware) for this, it supports JSON out of the box.

Comment: Unfortunately that isn't the answer I was looking for as I don't want to change the unit test. My android apps that I install for the customer aren't easily updated and they have that header. it would be easier for me to get the cakephp server to accept that header instead of changing over 400 tablets.

Comment: @MosesLiaoGZ You need to provide a little more info then. Are you trying to say that your Android app is sending `application/x-www-form-urlended` formatted data alongside a `Content-Type: application/json` header? Please add details to your question as to what the actual HTTP request of your Android app looks like (headers and data/body)!

Comment: my android application is trying to send the header `Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8` and the charset is the one that is causing the problem.

Comment: @MosesLiaoGZ I'm pretty sure that the charset will not cause the error that you're showing in your question (assuming you're using the latest CakePHP version). The body parser middleware will only use the string before the first `;`, it wouldn't even get to throwing that exception if it weren't able to fetch a registered type from the header. Again, please show what exactly the problematic HTTP requests looks like, and also include the related error (not the error that the test case triggers!).

Comment: I did a screenshot and it throws out error 400 via postman. I update the question with a screenshot

Comment: @MosesLiaoGZ Well that clears up things a little bit, but it would still be good to know what the request headers look like. From the screen it's already apparent that unlike in your test case, your actual request doesn't send the data via the POST body, but via the query string, meaning your request body is empty, which would cause [**a problem for JSON requests in CakePHP versions earlier than 4.1.6**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/pull/15112). So my first suggestion would be to upgrade your CakePHP dependency.

Comment: The latest cakphp in composer is 4.1.6 and the next version is 4.2.0RC so I think I hold it off for now